# Can I read Orson Scott Card's "Hidden Empire" before "Empire"?

Tags: suggested-order, orson-scott-card, empire

I bought Orson Scott Card's *Hidden Empire* today at a second-hand store and I just realized that it's actually a sequel. I've read the *Ender* and *Homecoming* series by Card, and I know reading them out of order would be a bad idea. I'm just wondering if this series is the same way or if it doesn't matter.

Can I read Orson Scott Card's "Hidden Empire" before "Empire"?

Also, I hope it goes without saying, but no spoilers, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You'll still get a few moments where you know how things have to turn out (like when you watch the Star Wars prequel trilogy, you know that Anakin has to become Vader), but it's still a fun book.

Comment: So, just to be clear, I will find out things in this book that happened in the first? Or, I would find out things in the first that happen in this one?

Comment: Have you read Hidden Empire yet? Your question sounded like you had. If you haven't, you can read it, but you'll know two major events that happen in Empire for at least two characters (one very minor, only mentioned character and one very major character, both of whom are major characters in Empire). But, like I said, it's like watching the Prequel trilogy after seeing the original, you know how characters turn out, but you don't know what makes them that way.